# Copy column values from one table to another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, copy

I'm trying to create a T-SQL query for several hours now. Google and the forum search did not help, so I hope someone can help me with this.

There are two tables, `Change` and `Journal`. Each row in `Change` has 5 related rows in `Journal`.

What I want to do is to copy the column value (`CreatedDateTime`) of a specific related row from `Journal` into the column `AuthorizationDate` of `Change`. This should be done for all rows in `Change`.

This is what I've achieved so far:

```
UPDATE Change 
SET Change.ap_ITSM_MDP_AuthorizationDate = 
    ( SELECT Journal.CreatedDateTime 
      FROM Journal 
        JOIN Change 
          ON Journal.Parentlink_RecID = Change.RecID 
      WHERE ITSM_ChangeNotes_Subject = 'Status changed to: Authorized' 
        AND Change.RecID = Journal.ParentLink_RecID
    )
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error message:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I thought I DID limit the result to one by the WHERE clause (`ChangeNotes_Subject = '...'`). What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
UPDATE Change 
SET Change.ap_ITSM_MDP_AuthorizationDate = 
    ( SELECT Journal.CreatedDateTime 
      FROM Journal 
      WHERE ITSM_ChangeNotes_Subject = 'Status changed to: Authorized' 
        AND Change.RecID = Journal.ParentLink_RecID
    ) ;
```

But using `JOIN` is better - to avoid any unwanted updates. Here's how:

```
UPDATE Change 
SET Change.ap_ITSM_MDP_AuthorizationDate = Journal.CreatedDateTime 
FROM Journal 
  JOIN Change 
    ON Change.RecID = Journal.ParentLink_RecID
WHERE ITSM_ChangeNotes_Subject = 'Status changed to: Authorized' ;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, that helped!
Seems sometimes less code is better ;)

Answer (score 1):

As you said, your Journal has five entries for the change's one... use top 1 or max in your subquery to prove that you can make this work. Then you have to consider which of the Journal entries to take the datetime from and alter your subselect to choose only that.

Oh and your "where" clause duplicates your join, discard that part. Also, which table is "ITSM_ChangeNotes_Subject" located, if it's in Change, that's probably the reason you're seeing duplicates in the returned Journal rows.

Run the subquery with an example change ID to see if you really are getting duplicate rows for your search string.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
I googled for possibilities to limit the results but only found "LIMIT" which seems to work only on MySQL...
I'll try that out

ITSM_ChangeNotes_Subject is part of the "Journal" table. There's always only one Journal entry with that specific subject.

I already ran my query with a single change, which did work but put the value from the journal entry related to that change into ALL changes.

Thank you very much for your answer. This helps newbies like me understand SQL better ;)

Comment: @user136868 No problems, I'm glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Change 
SET Change.ap_ITSM_MDP_AuthorizationDate = 
    ( SELECT TOP 1 Journal.CreatedDateTime 
      FROM Journal 
        JOIN Change 
          ON Journal.Parentlink_RecID = Change.RecID 
      WHERE ITSM_ChangeNotes_Subject = 'Status changed to: Authorized' 
        AND Change.RecID = Journal.ParentLink_RecID
    )
```

Note: Careful to use this query because subquery will return only one row which is expected by you or not, that i have doubt.

Comment: Hello DynamicVariable,

thank you, ypercube's solution worked for me, but i'll try yours, too :)